# Converter símbolo  para String (%F0%9F%8C%A0)

Tags: delphi

O símbolo  é igual a `%F0%9F%8C%A0`, mas como eu posso converte-lo no Delphi?

Tentei várias *UrlEncoders*, mas nenhuma delas retornou o resultado correto.

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
 for i := 1 to length(s) do
    result:= result+IntToHex(ord(s[i]),2);
```

Mas o resultado é `D83CDF20`

Comment: A conversão depende de uma série de coisas, depende de onde você está obtendo os dados. Basicamente basta pegar cada um dos bytes que compõe o caractere, e converter para hexadecimal.

Comment: e quais foram os resultados que você obteve até agora?

Comment: Veja um exemplo em PHP http://ideone.com/t6n2HA

Comment: oi mais ou menos isso que eu tentei @Bacco for i := 1 to length(s) do result:= result+IntToHex(ord(s[i]),2); mas o meu resultado é diferente esse é o meu resultado D83CDF20

Comment: @CP8M Cada encoding guarda o caractere de uma maneira, quando você diz "O símbolo  é igual a %F0%9F%8C%A0" não é sempre verdade. Depende do encoding. O resultado que você quer provavelmente é UTF-8, mas o Delphi deve guardar em outro formato.

Comment: Não sei se é meu computador, mas é esse símbolo? http://i.imgur.com/LfWnlF9.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Encontrei seu problema também no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776302/standard-url-encode-function), a Indy `TIdURI` não consegue fazer isso nas versões atuais do Delphi sem possuir acesso a sua `Unit` (que não o acompanha mais). Então existe uma função capaz de fazer isto, na verdade, varias!

Vamos usar um método e ver se chegamos ao que você pretende!

```
function frmTeste.EncodeURIComponent(const ASrc: string): UTF8String;
const
  HexMap: UTF8String = '0123456789ABCDEF';

  function IsSafeChar(ch: Integer): Boolean;
  begin
    if (ch >= 48) and (ch <= 57) then Result := True    // 0-9
    else if (ch >= 65) and (ch <= 90) then Result := True  // A-Z
    else if (ch >= 97) and (ch <= 122) then Result := True  // a-z
    else if (ch = 33) then Result := True // !
    else if (ch >= 39) and (ch <= 42) then Result := True // '()*
    else if (ch >= 45) and (ch <= 46) then Result := True // -.
    else if (ch = 95) then Result := True // _
    else if (ch = 126) then Result := True // ~
    else Result := False;
  end;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  ASrcUTF8: UTF8String;
begin
  Result := '';

  ASrcUTF8 := UTF8Encode(ASrc);

  I := 1; J := 1;
  SetLength(Result, Length(ASrcUTF8) * 3);

  while I <= Length(ASrcUTF8) do
  begin
    if IsSafeChar(Ord(ASrcUTF8[I])) then
    begin
      Result[J] := ASrcUTF8[I];
      Inc(J);
    end
    else if ASrcUTF8[I] = ' ' then
    begin
      Result[J] := '+';
      Inc(J);
    end
    else
    begin
      Result[J] := '%';
      Result[J+1] := HexMap[(Ord(ASrcUTF8[I]) shr 4) + 1];
      Result[J+2] := HexMap[(Ord(ASrcUTF8[I]) and 15) + 1];
      Inc(J,3);
    end;
    Inc(I);
  end;

  SetLength(Result, J-1);
end;
```

Para usar a função faça isto:

```
edtFonteDeDados.Text := EncodeURIComponent('');
```

Faça os testes, aguardo o Feedback!